# How can I plot data from reactive dataframe and fix the error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am completely new to R shiny apps and I am currently trying to create a simple app to visualize some gene expression data from an RNA-sequencing experiment. I am trying to pass a textInput (a gene name) to the UI, so that the server can take it as an input to get the data from a data frame and plot it for that speficic gene using ggplot. My code (so far) is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("gene", "Please enter a gene of interest (Examples: IL2, CD28, LDLR):"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    #Read data file and convert to a matrix 
    raw_df <- read_csv("C:/path/file.csv")
    matsymbol <- as.matrix(raw_df[, 2:21])
    row.names(matsymbol) <-  raw_df$...1
    
    
    ## The gene is found in the matsymbol to extract all normalized read counts 
    ## A matrix of dim=5x4 is formed 
    gene_counts <- t(matrix(matsymbol[input$gene,], nrow=4))
    
    ## Define rownames for the matrix 
    rownames(gene_counts) <- c("Non-stimulated", 
                               "Stimulated, 24h", 
                               "Stimulated, 48h", 
                               "Stimulated, 48h + LV", 
                               "Stimulated, 72h + LV")
    
    ## Calculate rowMeans and rowSDs for each row in the matrix 
    row_means_gene <- rowMeans(gene_counts)
    row_sds_gene <- rowSds(gene_counts)
    
    ## Collect to a dataframe which can be used for ggplot  
    df_gene <- as.data.frame(cbind(row_means_gene, row_sds_gene))
    
  })
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    req(data1())
    
    ## Plot the expression using ggplot 
    p_gene <- ggplot(df_gene, aes(x=rownames(df_gene), y=row_means_gene, fill = rownames(df_gene))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", color="grey", position=position_dodge(), width = 0.7) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=row_means_gene-row_sds_gene, ymax=row_means_gene+row_sds_gene), width=0.2,
                    position=position_dodge(.9), color = "#404040") + 
      scale_fill_manual("Condition", values = c("Non-stimulated" = "blue", 
                                                "Stimulated, 24h" = "red", 
                                                "Stimulated, 48h" = "green",
                                                "Stimulated, 48h + LV" = "yellow",
                                                "Stimulated, 72h + LV" = "black")) + 
      labs(x="Condition", y = "Normalized expression (read counts) +/- s.d.") +
      ggtitle(label = "Normalized expression") + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust=1))
    p_gene
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data from the raw_df (first col are gene names):

```
...1          A1      A2      A3      A4      B1      B2     B3      B4     C1      C2      C3     C4     D1     D2      D3      D4      E1     E2      E3     E4
   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 DDX11L1   135.      2.45   24.0     8.77 0       9.14e-1 5.85e0 9.27e-1 1.12e0 1.97e+0 0       5.03e0 7.05e0 2.03e0 9.27e-1 3.27e+0 8.53e-1 0      9.38e-1 1.90e0
 2 MIR6859-1   1.16   24.5    32.0    13.2  1.03e+1 9.14e-1 1.42e1 9.27e+0 3.35e0 0       8.76e+0 3.35e0 6.04e0 2.03e0 1.20e+1 3.27e+0 0       1.66e1 2.06e+1 1.05e1
 3 DDX11L1    59.2     6.12   34.7    23.4  1.87e+0 1.83e+0 8.35e0 7.41e+0 1.12e0 4.92e+0 1.75e+0 8.38e0 5.03e0 3.05e0 3.71e+0 4.90e+0 1.11e+1 2.38e0 5.63e+0 7.61e0
 4 MIR6859-2  16.2     6.12    2.67   10.2  9.36e-1 5.48e+0 4.18e0 9.27e-1 2.23e0 0       8.76e-1 0      5.03e0 1.02e0 0       8.17e-1 1.71e+0 3.96e0 3.75e+0 1.90e0
 5 FAM87B     55.7    44.1    56.0   142.   3.74e+0 8.22e+0 1.67e0 2.59e+1 3.35e0 9.84e-1 5.25e+0 2.18e1 1.01e0 7.12e0 2.78e+0 2.29e+1 1.54e+1 7.92e0 1.59e+1 3.52e1
 6 LINC00115  81.2    73.4    30.7   127.   8.42e+0 9.14e+0 1.42e1 1.76e+1 1.12e1 6.89e+0 7.88e+0 1.01e1 9.06e0 9.16e0 1.39e+1 1.63e+1 7.68e+0 1.74e1 2.72e+1 3.61e1
```

Data from the df_gene (example gene):

```
                     row_means_gene row_sds_gene
Non-stimulated               0.0000       0.0000
Stimulated, 24h           2692.3108    2627.0944
Stimulated, 48h            827.6718     823.3256
Stimulated, 48h + LV      1762.1866    1995.1224
Stimulated, 72h + LV       122.9962     144.6482
```

I learned that I should have my data wrapped in reactive() when using the input$, however, I am running into multiple different problems. First of all, I am getting the error  `error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': subscript out of bounds`. I know that it has something to do with the reactivity, and I have tried to look around on multiple forums for an answer, but I just can't figure out how to put it right. Secondly, I am not quite sure what to pass to the ggplot - the dataframe (df_gene) is inside the reactive element data1, so how can I tell it to find it? Can I use something like data1()$df_gene?

I really hope this is not trivial/a stupid question, otherwise I apologize.
Thank you so much in advance and all the best,
Lasse

Comment: Please provide some (rows of) example data of `raw_df` rather than `read_csv()`. People cannot help you much without some data.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to help you without underlying data to run the code and troubleshoot. One thing I noted is that you are using df_gene as the data for the plot. df_gene is being generated inside the reactive function and as the last step, should be what gets returned by the function. You have called the returned value data1.  So you will want to use that as the data source for your plot.  ggplot(data1(), aes( etc....).

Comment: @bdedu and stomper, thank you so much for your comments! I tried to add some example data now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not related to reactivity, but at first let me say something - I really do not work with row names, so perhaps I'm missing something.

However, I have checked this (rownames, subsetting) and see that:

```
raw_df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      ...1 = c("DDX11L1",
                               "MIR6859-1","DDX11L1","MIR6859-2","FAM87B",
                               "LINC00115"),
                A1 = c(135, 1.16, 59.2, 16.2, 55.7, 81.2),
                A2 = c(2.45, 24.5, 6.12, 6.12, 44.1, 73.4),
                A3 = c(24, 32, 34.7, 2.67, 56, 30.7),
                A4 = c(8.77, 13.2, 23.4, 10.2, 142, 127),
                B1 = c(0, 10.3, 1.87, 0.936, 3.74, 8.42),
                B2 = c(0.914, 0.914, 1.83, 5.48, 8.22, 9.14),
                B3 = c(5.85, 14.2, 8.35, 4.18, 1.67, 14.2),
                B4 = c(0.927, 9.27, 7.41, 0.927, 25.9, 17.6),
                C1 = c(1.12, 3.35, 1.12, 2.23, 3.35, 11.2),
                C2 = c(1.97, 0, 4.92, 0, 0.984, 6.89),
                C3 = c(0, 8.76, 1.75, 0.876, 5.25, 7.88),
                C4 = c(5.03, 3.35, 8.38, 0, 21.8, 10.1),
                D1 = c(7.05, 6.04, 5.03, 5.03, 1.01, 9.06),
                D2 = c(2.03, 2.03, 3.05, 1.02, 7.12, 9.16),
                D3 = c(0.927, 12, 3.71, 0, 2.78, 13.9),
                D4 = c(3.27, 3.27, 4.9, 0.817, 22.9, 16.3),
                E1 = c(0.853, 0, 11.1, 1.71, 15.4, 7.68),
                E2 = c(0, 16.6, 2.38, 3.96, 7.92, 17.4),
                E3 = c(0.938, 20.6, 5.63, 3.75, 15.9, 27.2),
                E4 = c(1.9, 10.5, 7.61, 1.9, 35.2, 36.1)
        )
matsymbol <- as.matrix(raw_df[, 2:21])
row.names(matsymbol) <-  raw_df$...1
input_gene <- "What should I choose?"
t(matrix(matsymbol[input_gene ,], nrow=4))
```

Gives you the same error if the `input$gene` (`input_gene` above) do not exists in the data frame / matrix. Or - more precisely - this what below gives you the same error:

```
input_gene <- ""
t(matrix(matsymbol[input_gene ,], nrow=4))
```

Because the empty `textInput` (and it is empty when the app starts) means `""`

You can use the code below to get empty matrix instead of error:

```
t(matrix(matsymbol[rownames(matsymbol) == input_gene ,], nrow=4))
```

But you will have another problem if you get matrix with 0 rows - next line, i.e.:

```
rownames(gene_counts) <- c("Non-stimulated", 
                               "Stimulated, 24h", 
                               "Stimulated, 48h", 
                               "Stimulated, 48h + LV", 
                               "Stimulated, 72h + LV")
```

won't work, because you will get NULL for `rownames()`, like in this example:

```
rownames(matrix()[FALSE, ])
```

In other words, you would need at first to check if you have matrix with 4 rows to set the 4-length character vector as a names of rows. Or it will be better to gives the user possibility to choose the gene from the predefined list of genes? Check out the `selectInput()` function. However, because you are reading the file in the `server` part, you would need to familiarize yourself with `updateSelectInput()` function as well. Think about it, try it if you think it is wort to do this and if you would need help with "How to display values in `selectInput()`?" you can always ask another question here.

Notabene: I had a problem with function `rowSds()`, I have found it is from `genefilter` package, but I couldn't install this package (not available for my version of R), so I didn't check next steps in your app.